# find location of directory containing downloaded file in overall file system

Tags: unix, find, ls

To find location of the drectory in file system:
I tried

```
ls 'filename'
```

but, it just returned it's own file name.

with find command it also made same result.

is it becasue the file is on home directory? or did I used wrong command?

Comment: try `find . -name 'filname'` it will search in all dir starting from current dir

Comment: `ls` be default list files in current directory only

Comment: 'man command' (ex. 'man man' or 'man ls' or 'man find') gives detailed instructions for using the command.

Comment: To search the entire available storage: `find / -name 'filename`. If you downloaded from a browser it's probably somewhere in your home directory, `find $HOME -name filename`.